# problem installing android_core

Tags: android-core, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ve been following http://wiki.ros.org/android/Tutorials/hydro/Installation%20-%20Ros%20Development%20Environment.

after completing the rosjava tutorials i tried to install ros_android_core, since i am triing to build an app for my tablet.

when doing

```
wstool init -j4 ~/android/src https://raw.github.com/rosjava/rosjava/hydro/android_core.rosinstall
```

i get the error

```
Using initial elements from: https://raw.github.com/rosjava/rosjava/hydro/android_core.rosinstall
ERROR in config: Unable to download URL [https://raw.github.com/rosjava/rosjava/hydro/android_core.rosinstall]: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

can someone help me

Thanks

Stefan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188420/problem-installing-android_core/) by [stefan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19765/stefan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It could be that you're just hitting a transient network error. Try again and see if it works now.

Alternatively, there could be something wrong with your network configuration (although unlikely). Try to see whether this succeeds:

```
$ nslookup raw.github.com
```

Also make sure you have no http(s) proxy configured anywhere. It might be interfering.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stefan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19765/stefan/) on 2014-07-31**:
thanks - solved

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-07-31**:
So what was it in the end? Transient error? Proxy?

Also: on this site answers are accepted by clicking the check mark at the left of an answer. We rarely close questions, as there might still be some discussion.

**Comment by [stefan](https://answers.ros.org/users/19765/stefan/) on 2014-07-31**:
proxy settings